# Spring TCP Client without Transformer

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I followed [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server) example for setting up a TCP Client in Spring. Below is my `tcpClientServerDemo-context.xml` file where the transformer lies. Can someone help me remove the transformer and send the data as it is without any modifications? If I try to remove the line `reply-channel='clientBytes2StringChannel'` or even make it null, I get exceptions when building the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder />

    <!-- Client side -->

    <int:gateway id="gw"
                 service-interface="hello.SimpleGateway"
                 default-request-channel="input"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                                   type="client"
                                   host="192.86.33.61"
                                   serializer="CustomSerializerDeserializer"
                                   deserializer="CustomSerializerDeserializer"
                                   port="${availableServerSocket}"
                                   single-use="true"
                                   so-timeout="10000"/>

    <bean id="CustomSerializerDeserializer" class="hello.CustomSerializerDeserializer" />

    <int:channel id="input" />

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
                                 request-channel="input"
                                 connection-factory="client"
                                 request-timeout="10000"
                                 reply-timeout="10000"/>

    <!-- Server side -->
    <!-- When creating the socket factory on the server side, we specify both the serializer and deserializer
    which deals with both accepting a stream formatted with the Stx-Etx bytes as well as sending a stream
    formatted with the Stx-Etx bytes. -->
    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverConnectionFactory"
                                   type="server"
                                   port="${availableServerSocket}"
                                   single-use="true"
                                   so-linger="10000"
                                   serializer="Custom1SerializerDeserializer"
                                   deserializer="Custom1SerializerDeserializer"/>


    <bean id="Custom1SerializerDeserializer" class="hello.CustomSerializerDeserializer1" />

    <int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
                                connection-factory="serverConnectionFactory"
                                request-channel="incomingServerChannel"
                                error-channel="errorChannel"/>

    <!-- We leave a message listener off of this channel on purpose because we hook
    one up before the test actually runs (see the unit test associated with this
    context file) -->
    <int:channel id="incomingServerChannel" />

</beans>
```

**EDIT:**

Now I am able to send the messages using a custom serializer/deserializer. But unfortunately, I am unable to receive the responses. Here is my serializer/deserializer:

```
public class CustomSerializerDeserializer implements Serializer<String>, Deserializer<String> {
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

public void serialize(String input, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    logger.info("inside serialize");
    outputStream.write(buildSampleMsg(input));
    outputStream.flush();
}

public String deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    logger.info("inside deserialize");
    final int bufferSize = 1024;
    final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    for (;;) {
        int rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (rsz < 0) {
            break;
        }
        out.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
    }
    logger.info(out.toString());
    return out.toString();
}

public byte[] buildSampleMsg(String body){
    logger.info("inside buildsamplemsg");
    ......
    return hexStringToByteArray(data);
}
```

I have some logging done on the first line of the serializer/deserializer but the log is never printed. Which in turn means, we don't get any response. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the reply-channel is correct. You don't give any indication of the error, but the gateway interface method return type must be changed to byte[].

**EDIT**

Clearly you are doing something wrong if the mainframe is getting junk. You should do the EBCDIC conversion after you convert your "ABCD" to a `byte[]` (with `getBytes()`); if you have EBCDIC chars in a String, that won't work. Also, bear in mind the default serializer will add CRLF (ascii) to the output. If that mainframe can determine the end of message from the data itself, you can use a `ByteArrayRawSerializer` in the `serializer` attribute. However, you will need a custom `deserializer` because the framework won't know how to construct a message from the stream; unless the mainframe closes the socket after sending the reply, in which case a `ByteArrayRawSerializer` will work as the `deserializer` attribute.

A common technique used to communicate with mainframes (and others) is to use a 1, 2, or 4 byte length header (network byte order). The `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` does just that.

If the mainframe is expecting EBCDIC delimiters, you'll need a custom serializer/deserializer - it might make more sense to do the EBCDIC conversion there, separating it from your application logic.

You can read about serializers/deserializers [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories).

> TCP is a streaming protocol; this means that some structure has to be provided to data transported over TCP, so the receiver can demarcate the data into discrete messages. Connection factories are configured to use (de)serializers to convert between the message payload and the bits that are sent over TCP. This is accomplished by providing a deserializer and serializer for inbound and outbound messages respectively. A number of standard (de)serializers are provided.
>
> The `ByteArrayCrlfSerializer`, converts a byte array to a stream of bytes followed by carriage return and linefeed characters (`\r\n`). This is the default (de)serializer and can be used with telnet as a client, for example.

Comment: Yes I changed it to byte[]. So what I am trying is actually convert some user input from the user like ABCD to its HEX format like '41424344' and send to a mainframe system as bytes. But when received on mainframe happens to be some random value like 00000030. When the same done using a normal java socket implementation goes through without any issues.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more details; if the mainframe is IBM or similar, it might be expecting EBCDIC, not ASCII, which means you will need transformers for both the request and reply.

Comment: Well yes it is IBM Mainframe. I use some internal processing logics to build a message as EBCDIC itself and then try to send that data as bytes. So in this case, I don't need a transformer right? Either ways, I am sending the EBCDIC data.

Comment: I am on vacation so my replies will be sporadic, at best; see the edit to my answer.

Comment: thanks! I have implemented the client connection request part using custom serializer/deserializer. Working on the client response part. Thanks a lot for the pointers. Will ask for more help if needed!

Comment: I have updated the question with some issues I am having on the receive part. Could you again point me in the right direction?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration`. If you still can't figure it out from the logs, ask a new question showing your complete configuration/code and the relevant portion of the log. I don't know why you don't get the "inside deserialize" message but, in any case, your `for` loop will never end - it's waiting for the socket to close. As I said, the deserializer needs some intelligent way to know the message is complete - reading into a byte[] like that could cause you to get part of the next message.

Comment: true but have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799702/spring-tcp-socket-client-not-receiving-data-from-mainframe Why does it go to the deserializer even before going to the serializer?