# Spring TCP Socket Integration Implementation not passing gateway.send method

Tags: sockets, tcp, spring-integration

So I am wrapping the Spring Integration TCP client to provide APIs for my application. Previous questions regarding this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367943/spring-tcp-client-without-transformer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799702/spring-tcp-socket-client-not-receiving-data-from-mainframe). The problem with this is that the `gateway.send()` doesn't end at all and the API response never comes back.

Here is my `ServerConnection.java` file:

```
package com.abc.xyz.serverconnection;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;   
public class ServerConnections {    
    private SimpleGateway gateway;    
    public ServerConnections() {
        final GenericXmlApplicationContext context = setupContext();
        this.setGateway(context.getBean(SimpleGateway.class));
    }    
    public static GenericXmlApplicationContext setupContext() {
        final GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.load("classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/tcpClientServerDemo-context.xml");
        context.registerShutdownHook();
        context.refresh();
        return context;
    }    
    public SimpleGateway getGateway() {
        return gateway;
    }    
    public void setGateway(SimpleGateway gateway) {
        this.gateway = gateway;
    }    
    public boolean sendData(String input) {
        this.gateway.send(input);
        return true;
    }    
    public void recieveData(String output) {
        System.out.println("Data from server:" + output);
    }    
}
```

In my controller, I do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logon", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String logon() {
    // logics go here and the result is stored like below and sent
    String message = "0000005401F40000C1E3E304010000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004040404040404040C1E3E300C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8E8C5E2C8E6C1D540F1F7F24BF0F1F64BF0F0F34BF0F5F200";
    if (serverConnections.sendData(message)) {
        return "Data sent successfully!";
    } else {
        return "Data not sent!";
    }
}
```

Here is how my config looks like:

```
    <context:property-placeholder />
    <int:channel id="input" />
    <int:channel id="toSA" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
                           ref="echoService"
                           method="recieveData"/>
    <bean id="echoService" class="com.abc.xyz.serverconnection.ServerConnection" />
    <bean id="CustomSerializerDeserializer" class="com.abc.xyz.serverconnection.CustomSerializerDeserializer" />
    <int:object-to-string-transformer id="serverBytes2String"
                                      input-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
                                      output-channel="toSA"/>
    <int:gateway id="gw"
                 service-interface="com.abc.xyz.serverconnection.SimpleGateway"
                 default-request-channel="input"/>
    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                                   type="client"
                                   host="<ip>"
                                   serializer="CustomSerializerDeserializer"
                                   deserializer="CustomSerializerDeserializer"
                                   port="6100"
                                   single-use="false" />
    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
                                 request-channel="input"
                                 reply-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
                                 connection-factory="client" />
```

EDIT: Not able to get the DEBUG log of the application since I am using the TCP client implementation as a Maven Module inside a Maven Project. Another module uses this as a dependency and that is where the REST API end-points reside at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your

```
 <int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
                       ref="echoService"
                       method="recieveData"/>
```

Doesn't return any result to be sent to the `replyChannel` header, meanwhile your `gateway.send()` isn't a `void` method. That's how it waits for the reply which never comes back.

Comment: The TCP outbound gateway will time out after 5 seconds and the thread will sit in the gateway waiting for a reply that will never come. Set the `default-reply-timeout` on the `gw` to 5000 to match. If you don't want to wait for a reply, change the method to return `void` or set the `default-reply-timeout` to 0. As @artem said, you should really use a channel adapter for send-only operations.

Comment: @artem @gary thanks for your inputs. I have changed the gateway to return `void`. This works but I would like to understand @artem's point. My `EchoService` returns a `void` but `gateway.send()`  returns a string. So does that mean I need to catch the `gateway.send()`'s response somehwere? I don't get the point.

Comment: `EchoService` returning `void` seems like an oxymoron to me :) (I realize you got the name from the sample). A gateway method that returns non-void tells the framework that a reply is expected; when the thread returns to the gateway it waits for that reply. There's a timeout, but by default it's infinity. Since you return void from your service, the flow ends at that point, and the reply will never arrive. A gateway method that returns `void` tells the framework that no reply will ever come. For request/reply messaging, it's generally better to block the calling thread until the reply arrives.

Comment: Gateway's method contract dictates the downstream flow behavior. If you have non-`void` return type it turns to the `request/reply` scenario; and after sending a request it waits for the reply. The default `reply-timeout` is indefinite. That's why your call is blocked forever. See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway